# SQL Join and sort

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, join, alias

I have a MYSQL table of sports team results. Each event or match is stored with a `for` and `against` goals scored value. What I would like to do is retrieve an ordered list matches order by goals conceeded (ascending).

It seems simple enough until the team in question is the away team:

- in which case we are looking at goals at `for`.
- When the team in question is the home team we are looking at goals 'against'.

I can written the following query:

```
(SELECT * FROM `matches`,`teams`,`outcomes` 
WHERE `home_team_id`=11 AND `matches`.away_team_id=`teams`.team_id  
AND `matches`.score_id=`outcomes`.outcome_id 
ORDER BY `against`,`date` DESC LIMIT 0,20)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `matches`,`teams`,`outcomes` 
WHERE `away_team_id`=11 AND `matches`.home_team_id=`teams`.team_id  
AND `matches`.score_id=`outcomes`.outcome_id 
ORDER BY `for`,`date` DESC LIMIT 0,20)
```

It works but the result set is in two halves, I want to combine the results and order by conceeded whether the team is home or away. Do I need an alias to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the table structures? I understand what you're trying to do but without the structures there's too much guesswork - for example I'm not sure whether `for`, `against` and `date` are in `matches` or `outcomes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make a UNION query with the fields you need, **renaming the for or against fields so that they have the same name**. Then select everything from this table union and order by the renamed field:

```sql
select * from
((SELECT matches.*, teams.*, outcomes.against as goals
FROM matches,teams,outcomes
WHERE
    matches.home_team_id=11
    AND matches.away_team_id=teams.team_id  
    AND matches.score_id=outcomes.outcome_id
)
UNION
(SELECT matches.*, teams.*, outcomes.for as goals
FROM matches,teams,outcomes 
WHERE matches.away_team_id=11
    AND matches.home_team_id=teams.team_id  
    AND matches.score_id=outcomes.outcome_id
)) as union_table
order by goals, date desc limit 0,20;
```

This query executes perfectly in MySQL database.

Comment: Great thanks, I worked some very similar out, again using an alias. In writing it down it made me better understand the problem. Hopefulyl someone else will also find this of use.

Answer (score 0):

since you already have the two halves you can just select everything from your query and sort accordingly:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
(SELECT * FROM `matches`,`teams`,`outcomes` 
WHERE `home_team_id`=11 AND `matches`.away_team_id=`teams`.team_id  
AND `matches`.score_id=`outcomes`.outcome_id 
ORDER BY `against`,`date` DESC LIMIT 0,20)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `matches`,`teams`,`outcomes` 
WHERE `away_team_id`=11 AND `matches`.home_team_id=`teams`.team_id  
AND `matches`.score_id=`outcomes`.outcome_id 
ORDER BY `for`,`date` DESC LIMIT 0,20)
) as results order by results.conceeded asc
```